# Conditionally moving the position of a single data label in a pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following sample code will generate the donut chart I'll use as my example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Following should supposedly set the font correctly:
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Muli'] + plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']
plt.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'extra bold'

size_of_groups=[12,11,30,0.3]

colors = ['#a1daaa','#bbbbb4','#444511','#1afff2']

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.color'] = '#273859'

# Create a pieplot
my_pie,texts,_ = plt.pie(size_of_groups,radius = 1.2,colors=colors,autopct="%.1f%%",
textprops = {'color':'w',                                                                                           
             'size':15  #, 'weight':"extra bold"
            }, pctdistance=0.75, labeldistance=0.7) #pctdistance and labeldistance change label positions.
labels=['High','Low','Normal','NA']
plt.legend(my_pie,labels,loc='lower center',ncol=2,bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.2))
plt.setp(my_pie, width=0.6, edgecolor='white') 
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.show()
```

The above outputs this:

[image: img]

Mostly, this is great. Finally I got a nice looking donut chart!

But there is just one last thing to finesse - when the portion of the donut chart is very small (like the 0.6%), I need the labels to be moved out of the chart, and possibly colored black instead.

I managed to do something similar for bar charts using plt.text, but I don't think that will be feasible with pie charts at all. I figure someone has definitely solved a similar problem before, but I can't readily fine any decent solutions.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239733/matplotlib-move-labels-into-middle-of-pie-chart) suggests some alternatives to cope with the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to move all percent-texts for patches smaller than some given amount (5 degrees in the code example).  Note that this will also fail when there would be multiple small pieces close to each other.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

size_of_groups = [12, 11, 30, 0.3]
colors = ['#a1daaa', '#bbbbb4', '#444511', '#1afff2']
my_pie, texts, pct_txts = plt.pie(size_of_groups, radius=1.2, colors=colors, autopct="%.1f%%",
                                  textprops={'color': 'w', 'size': 15}, pctdistance=0.75,
                                  labeldistance=0.7)
labels = ['High', 'Low', 'Normal', 'NA']
plt.legend(my_pie, labels, loc='lower center', ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.2))
plt.setp(my_pie, width=0.6, edgecolor='white')

for patch, txt in zip(my_pie, pct_txts):
    if (patch.theta2 - patch.theta1) <= 5:
        # the angle at which the text is normally located
        angle = (patch.theta2 + patch.theta1) / 2.
        # new distance to the pie center
        x = patch.r * 1.2 * np.cos(angle * np.pi / 180)
        y = patch.r * 1.2 * np.sin(angle * np.pi / 180)
        # move text to new position
        txt.set_position((x, y))
        txt.set_color('black')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting pie]

Comment: Once again, I sit here with my jaw dropped, wondering "how the hell could he have known that". Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted a solution by tweaking the solution of [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) on a different problem given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789111/4932316). For some reason, the percentage sign is not being displayed in my system but you can figure that out

```
rad = 1.2 # Define a radius variable for later use

my_pie, texts, autotexts = plt.pie(size_of_groups, radius=rad, colors=colors, autopct="%.1f%%",
                     pctdistance=0.75, labeldistance=0.7, textprops={'color':'white', 'size':20}) 

# Rest of the code

cx, cy = 0, 0 # Center of the pie chart 

for t in autotexts:
    x, y = t.get_position()
    text = t.get_text()

    if float(text.strip('%')) < 1: # Here 1 is the target threshold percentage
        angle = np.arctan2(y-cy, x-cx)
        xt, yt = 1.1*rad*np.cos(angle)+cx, 1.1*rad*np.sin(angle)+cy
        t.set_color("k")
        t.set_position((xt,yt))
```

[image]